# Remotely use a local account to unlock another local account

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, batch-file, remote, wmi

So I have had an interesting problem pop up.  I am trying to make someones life easier by making a script to help reset local accounts on windows 7 machines.  Ideally, we'd like to do it remotely, so I made the following batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p machine=Please enter machine reference/ip:
set /p account=Please enter account name:
wmic /user:".\<adminaccountname>" /node:"%machine%" process call create "net user %account% /active:yes"
pause
```

With the result:

```
ERROR:
Description = User credentials cannot be used for local connections
```

Is there a way to achieve this, or do I simply need to use a domain account?  Would psexec allow me to do this?

Comment: I would use teamviewer to connect to the pc remotely, you can then login to another account and do it manually. If you can use a domain, you do not even need to access the pc. You can use Active Directory to reset a password.

Comment: RDP is an option, but it seems a little much for such a specific task, which is why I am trying wmic.  Also, the account isn't on AD, it's local to the machine (we use it to administer spiceworks and policy doesn't allow us to make it a domain account).

Comment: Commenting on whether you simply need to use a domain account, you can still RDP to a machine even if it's not on the domain. (If it were on the domain you'd need to use username machinename\username to log on). I think though you'll need to configure a password on the account that's being used to log on to the machine if it doesn't have a password already.

Comment: The local account which I am using referenced at `/user:".\<adminaccountname>"` has a password.  It is the same on each machine.

Comment: Try using `runas /netonly` to provide the admin credentials instead of using the `/user` in WMIC.